# Write XML filename based of CSV cell Python

Tags: python, csv

Trying to save output from this script to a file based on a cell within the csv. I am able to call the variable `{file_root_name}` to write into the xml file but not as a variable to write the file name. How can I use the variable `file_root_name` as a variable to generate a file name?

```
import csv
import sys

from xml.etree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring

from xml.dom import minidom

def prettify(elem):
    """Return a pretty-printed XML string for the Element.
    """
    rough_string = ElementTree.tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
    return reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="  ", encoding = 'utf-8')

doctype = '<!DOCTYPE smil PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SMIL 2.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/SMIL20.dtd">'

video_data = ((256, 336000),
              (512, 592000),
              (768, 848000),
              (1128, 1208000))

with open(sys.argv[1], 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        root = Element('smil')
        root.set('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language')
        head = SubElement(root, 'head')
        meta = SubElement(head, 'meta base="rtmp://cp23636.edgefcs.net/ondemand"')
        body = SubElement(root, 'body')

        switch_tag = ElementTree.SubElement(body, 'switch')

        for suffix, bitrate in video_data:

            attrs = {'src': ("mp4:soundcheck/{year}/{id}/{file_root_name}_{suffix}.mp4"
                             .format(suffix=str(suffix), **row)),
                     'system-bitrate': str(bitrate),
                     }
            ElementTree.SubElement(switch_tag, 'video', attrs)

        xml, doc = prettify(root).split('\n', 1)
        output = open('file_root_name'+'.smil', 'w')
        output.write(xml + doctype + doc)
        output.close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I follow, but if the line

```
  attrs = {'src': ("mp4:soundcheck/{year}/{id}/{file_root_name}_{suffix}.mp4"
                             .format(suffix=str(suffix), **row)),
                     'system-bitrate': str(bitrate),
                     }
```

works then "file_root_name" must be a string key of the dictlike object row.  The line

```
    output = open('file_root_name'+'.smil', 'w')
```

actually combines the *string* 'file_root_name' with '.smil'.  So you'd really want something like

```
    output = open(row['file_root_name']+'.smil', 'w')
```

BTW, the line

```
    output.close
```

won't do anything-- you want output.close() instead, or simply

```
with open(row['file_root_name']+'.smil', 'w') as output:
    output.write(xml + doctype + doc)
```

Comment: The line works but, if I try `print file_root_name` I get `NameError: name 'file_root_name' is not defined` So while it works within `attrs` it doesn't work as a variable.

Comment: It doesn't work because it's not a variable.  'file_root_name' is a key in the row dictionary, with some associated value (say "fred").  If you want one, though, simply use `file_root_name = row["file_root_name"]`.